# Debugging using Laravel Log files

Tags: laravel, debugging, logging

I am trying to isolate a problem in a backend logic using log file. I have made a custom log file for the purpose because default log file has too much content to filter through. The module is already live so I have to read the log file from the server to debug the problem. I noticed that while performing commit, the log files I created was in gitignore. So I wanted to know how it works. Are log files generally placed in gitignore? And do servers make their own log files?

Comment: You generally don't commit log files in source control, so git should ignore them (since source control is for source code).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the server will create its own log file. Version control should not work with them since the information they contain will be relative to the environment in which they are contained (your server in this case). Therefore, by default, in the storage/logs directory you will find a .gitignore file with the content:

```
*
! .gitignore
```

which will cause none of the files contained in it to be managed by Git.
If your new log file is in this directory, it will not be processed by Git either.

Comment: What about a custom log file? I cannot find it anywhere on the server. I made a debug.log file in local and deployed it. Of course, its in gitignore. What happens in that case?